# export and import document library from one site to a subsite using code?

Tags: 2010, development, export, import

This should be possible, I have find some examples but with list items, or entire sites, not with only a document library.

Id be happy if somebody can provide working code!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a response I posted elsewhere (the links below contain code segments. Export/Import SPWeb works with site, list, or document libraries) -

The quickest way would be to export the site/list/document library using the [Export-SPWeb](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428301.aspx#section1) PowerShell command. Use [Import-SPWeb](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607613.aspx) for importing the file package (it can also use optional compression. See the -Path and other options in the Export-SPWeb command).

An example showing the use of the above method - [Export / Import / Migrate document libraries across sites in SharePoint 2010](http://sharepoint-guru.blogspot.com/2010/11/export-import-migrate-document.html).

UPDATE: A near-equivalent using C# SPExport/SPImport is given here - [Using SPExport and SPImport: Part 1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/72521/Using-SPExport-and-SPImport-Part-1)

Comment: I need c# code not powershell of course!!

Comment: I have updated the above with a link to a similar example in C#